# How to make dynamic buttons in the ActionBar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I have ActionBar, where there is a "Delete" button. How to make so that after pressing this button disappeared all the buttons on ActioBar and appear two buttons "OK" and "Cancel".
Nowhere did not find the answer to this question, I will be glad for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never actually tried it but I have an idea in my mind..
1. On click of delete, set a flag to 1 (say delFlag=1 )2. Call 
    invalidateOptionsMenu()This will reload the menu items..
3. Now in onPrepareOptionsMenu, check whether the delFlag is set or not. If yes, then inflate the menu with your new options (viz., OK or cancel)
4. Now you can repeat the same on click of OK or cancel, but the other way round, i.e., set flag to 0 and inflate the menu layout with delete option in it..It should work this way.. Revert back in case you need more clarification..

EDIT-1 :

```
@Override public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
```

If(delFlag==1){ super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu); menu.findItem(R.id.ok).setVisible(true); menu.findItem(R.id.delete).setVisible(false); }return true; } //true or false depending on your requirements

Comment: These R.id.delete and R.id.ok are from you menu layout.. This is just for demo.. You may add for cancel also similarly..

Comment: Thank you so much? Method invalidateOptionsMenu () helped me. Before, I did not know how to update the menu.